# How to reliably reconstruct the DOM in real-time to do co-browsing (mirroring webpage usage)

Tags: javascript, screenshot, screensharing

There are some SaaS tools [[1](https://upscope.io/), [2](https://www.fullstory.com/features/)] that give you a plugin to run on your site, so that you can view how your users are interacting with your website remotely.

I'm guessing this works by streaming DOM updates back to a remote server, but I'm not sure of that.  I'm really interested in how this technology works, and whether or not there are tools out there to do similar tasks.

Here's the question:  How do they do it?  How can we reliably "co-browse" through the use of an installed Javascript snippet?  I know of some solutions using WebRTC, but the browser support doesn't seem to be there yet

Comment: There is no "right" way to do it so there can't be a right answer. Keep in mind that the majority of customers for them will be e-commerce and the technical barriers of e-commerce websites is fairly low, and add the fact that they want to market the "greatness" of their service. So they offer examples that will work. I've seen solutions that were dead simple (i.e. share url and share clicks). Anything above that becomes complicated beyond a simple answer.

Comment: I had a quick thought that there might be a HTML5 means to screen cast a browser page: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/

Comment: @cgTag What do you mean by there's no "right" way?  What I'm asking is how I can achieve what they are achieving.  If my customers install some JS code I give them on their website, then they can remote view users of their websites through a web portal, for example

Comment: @cgTag The screenshare link is interesting, thanks for sharing!  I will read through those :)

Comment: There are too many ways that use different approaches. Who's to say which way is right or best? A good question needs to be specific, should have source code examples and capable of having a clearly correct answer. I think the question is a good one, but not a stackoverflow one.

Comment: I totally get where you're coming from, and appreciate the conversation.  I avoided using the terms "right" or "best" in the problem description for that reason.  I do think there is a real solution to be made though, which is SO appropriate.  Reliably reproducing a browser through a JS snippet seems like a tough problem, but existing products show that this is achievable.  I'm asking how that is

Comment: At best, this is a request for a recommendation of a software tool. Maybe you can find an open source project that is working on this problem, and then you can post questions on how to specific use that library with examples of what you've tried.

Comment: @cgTag I guess if an open source "gold standard" tool exists, then yes it is asking for that.  However, I'm asking for how to actually solve this problem, which seems SO-worthy.  With that said, maybe I'm a bit mis-directed here and in the wrong - not sure :) Felt like the right place to ask, but if you think not, what's the right channel for this?

Comment: Try changing the question to be a specific technical question that will reveal the nature of what you seek. For example: "How can I monitor the websock data used by Upscope" with an example of what you've tried. Or how about "how can I unbundle the JS files to see what open source projects they are using"

Comment: What I seek is literally "How can I reconstruct webpage usage with Javascript/websockets?"

Comment: I found an open source project on the subject run by the Mozilla team. I don't think it gets more "standard" than that: https://togetherjs.com/

Comment: @cgTag Cool find!  I don't know that togetherjs fits the bill entirely: `TogetherJS relies on the same URL returning the same page`.  It seems to rely on content being static, rather than dynamic (If the page is locked behind a login, TogetherJS seems like it would fail)

Comment: That was my previous point. There are too many different ways to do it. If a vendor has found solutions they aren't going to be quick to let people know how they did it.

Comment: This mutation summary library seems like a potential starting point to a solution: https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary

Comment: I have doubts that will be reliable when running a JavaScript framework like Angular or React, but I have no proof of that. It's just that things like SVG and component CSS styles will make it very difficult to reproduce in another browser just by DOM inspection alone.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as [session replay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_replay).

> I'm guessing this works by streaming DOM updates back to a remote server

No, it probably doesn't care about DOM updates. The script would capture every single input *event*, including key presses, mouse moves, mouse clicks, scroll events etc. Those are what UX designers are usually care about when evaluating their page design. They also might capture the initial state of the DOM.

If those plugins are just for data acquisition (like in A/B tests), I don't think the plugin scripts do actually live-stream those events. It probably captures them, stores them in some compressed data structure, and sends it to the service provider when the user leaves the page or in regular intervals.

Live streaming would certainly be possible, and it seems to be that this is what that co-browsing plugin does. (There's apparently also a back channel - a huge security risk! - to trigger mouse clicks etc remotely). WebRTC (which also could feed the complete video) might one approach, but a [web socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) would be enough.

Some documentation on how togetherjs in particular does it can be found at https://togetherjs.com/docs/#technology-overview.

Comment: Can you add a link to https://togetherjs.com/ in your answer. Just for completeness.

Comment: @cgTag I was just going to do that after having reviewed it myself :-)